# Reporting in Crystal Reports with Formulas

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I want to create a formula for a table that looks like this but don't know what forumals to do to scan these files.

```
ID UDOfficer DATE 
1   6          Jan 
1   7          Jan 
1   9          Jan 
2   6          June 
3   6          April 
4   6          May 
5   5          Dec 
6   7          Nov 
7   6          April 
7   4          April
```

What I want to create:
A formula to put in a crosstab's column to capture UDOfficer = 6 and all others, but if UDOfficer is in 6, 7 and 9, the all others can not count that ID that was already counted for UDOFFICER 6.

```
OUTPUTCrosstable 

DATE   UDOFF6   UDOFFOTHER 
JAN     1            0 
APR     2            0            
MAY     1            0 
JUN     1            0 
NOV     0            1 
DEC     0            1
```

Comment: ok so what is the issue here?

Comment: I just am not sure what formulas to create. An IF ELSE Forumal to scan these files to make a result of this crosstab table. @Siva

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Grouping` as well as `IF Else` to make it work as per your requirement.

1. First create the group with `Date`.
2. Create 2 formulas and place in detail to count the occurrences.

Create a formula `@UDOFF6` and write below code:

```
if UDOfficer =6
then 1
else 0
```

Create another formula `UDOFFOTHER` and write below code:

```
if UDOfficer <> 6
then 1
else 0
```

Take sum of both formulas in group footer of `Date` your problem will be solved.

Comment: Would I then use @udoff6 and udoffother in the columns of the cross tab expert?

Comment: No need of crosstab use those normally in design